# Use subdirectory as "second" root

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For a project at my company I was assigned to create a front-facing site for our product. At this point it lives under its own subdirectory `/front` but I'd like the files to be accessible from the root directory without messing up any of the default behavior.

Example file structure:

```
/foo
...file.php
/bar
...index.php
...login.php
/front
.../css
.../js
...index.html
...page.html
```

I want to be able to access the files under `/front` as if they aren't even under a subdirectory. So when I go to http://website.com/ I would be seeing `/front/index.html`. I've accomplished this by adding this to the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ front/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) front/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The issue is now I can't seem to access `/foo` or `/bar`.

I'd appreciate any help I could get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it this way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^((?!front).*)$ front/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It seems as though it's not picking up the files from /front. For example if I go to / it doesn't display /front/index.html. Am I missing something here?

Comment: That works but then I'd have to enter in each of my directories into that rewrite rule (there are tons). Is there a way to do this without having to specify the exceptions? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I lied - it actually doesn't recognize sub-directories which don't have .htaccess files. Any idea how to fix that? I can't add .htaccess files to the other directories, unfortunately.

Comment: You mean a request for `/foo/file.php` goes to `/front/file/foo.php`?